# Facebook login - Make sessions last longer

Tags: php, facebook, session

I m using `loginFb` to log users in to my website. After about 30 min the user has to log in again. What can I do to extend the session of the user or extend the facebook token ... not really sure what needs to be done.

```
public function loginFb($facebookId)
    {
        $result = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, fb_id
        FROM users WHERE fb_id = ?");

        $result->bind_param('i', $facebookId);
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();
        $result->bind_result($id, $facebookId);

        if($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
                $soon = array();

                while ($result->fetch())
                {
                        $soon['id'] = $id;
                        $soon['fb_id'] = $facebookId;
                }

                $soonSess = serialize($soon);

                $_SESSION["user"] = $soonSess;
                $_SESSION["login_time"] = time();
                $_SESSION["logged_in"] = 1;
                $result->close();
                return true;

        }else{

                return false;

        }

    }
```

I also use the following rules for sessions:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
//ini_set('session.use_only_cookies',1);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 86400);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 86400);

ini_set('session.gc_probability', 0);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1000);
```

Can the session expire when a user logs out of their Facebook account? Or what is the best practice for a longer session lifetime when using Facebook login?

Edit **

```
//initialize Facebook
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
$helper = new FAcebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);

try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    die(" Error : " . $ex->getMessage());
}

//check if facebook session exists
if(isset($_SESSION['fb_token']))
{
    $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
}

if(isset($session))
{
    $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();

    try
    {
        $user = (new FacebookRequest(
            $session, 'GET', '/me'
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className())->asArray();

    } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    }

    $name = $user['name'];
    $firstName = $user['first_name'];
    $lastName = $user['last_name'];
    $fbId = $user['id'];
    $fbEmail = $user['email'];
}
```

Comment: You should consider just using the JS SDK for login. If you have it embedded into your pages, it will automatically get a fresh access token if necessary; and it can seamlessly share it with the PHP SDK via cookie.

Comment: I don't think it's the fb token ... I found the access token debuger and the token is valid Issued `1442549430 (4 hours ago)`
`Expires 1447733430 (in about 2 months)` I think it's the php garbage collector which cleans sessions. `/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime` gives me 24

Comment: So you are talking only about the edge case where the user is _not active_ on your site for 30 minutes …?

Comment: I guess ... that must be it. Not sure what edge case means.

Comment: By “edge case” I meant that it is not the usual use case, to login to any site, and then leaving it inactive (not doing anything on it) for extended amounts of time – although it might of course happen, user being busy on other sites in different tabs, going to lunch and using your site again when coming back, etc. – but that is not a Facebook-specific problem, that would happen on any site that uses a session-based login system and does have a limited session lifetime (which is usually what one wants, for security reasons).

Comment: So increase the session lifetime in your PHP configuration, if you think that’s the best way to go here, or maye use AJAX to “ping” your server in regular intervals, even when the user is not active on your site, so that the session’s last access timestamp gets updated  … or simply tell the user that they have to login again, if they leave your page “unattended” in their browser for longer periods of time.

Comment: That's my problem ... i ve been messing with the php.ini and no luck. I don't want the garbage collector to run at all. Or set the probability really really low.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the short-lived user access token (valid 2 hours) into a long-lived one (valid 60 days) by calling

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Comment: I m not sure where to add that code. I added some of my facebook config file. Can you please take a look at my edit? Do I change this: `$_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();`?

Comment: No, just make an additional `FacebookRequest` as outlined in my answer with `$_SESSION['fb_token']` as `{short-lived-token}`. You need to **exchange** the short-lived token to a long-lived one.

Comment: An example would help so much ... I just don't get it. I don't use Facebook login too much.